# Where should services be provided for best practices and/or optimization?

Tags: angular, angular5

For example I have a dialog component that is part of a module with other components. I placed the logic of the dialog component to a service. The problem is I don't know which is the best place to provide that service to. Should it be provided on that encompassing module or locally to that dialog component?

If it's provided locally on `@Component()` will it get created and destroyed along with the dialog's create and destroy life cycle? Is this a better or worse solution in the long run?

Update: I'm not sure yet whether I will need to use the service across other modules. Previous experience tells me it's almost always better to provide it to a module since a new feature often requires me to have access to the service from a different component. I'm just worried if I'm creating unnecessary overhead in anticipation of a future requirement.

Comment: This depends on how localized the service will become in the hierarchy of components, if it is used across modules and if it needs to be used in sandboxed mode (not a singleton). Can you provide these details?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post.

Comment: Based upon your update, I would tell you the intent/best practice is to register the provider as locally as you can (deepest part of the component hierarchy) first. Then, if you need it elsewhere at a later time, then refactor the register the provider higher (but still as low as possible) in the hierarchy. Your thoughts are correct in terms of performance and overhead.